# Is using UUIDs as Hibernate primary key ids considered bad design?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, uuid

Recently I wrote a little program, nothing noteworthy, mostly to test out some new things I found that don't really fit any real life application at the time. One of these things was using UUIDs instead of sequence-generated (by the underlying Oracle database) IDs for my Hibernate entities.

A colleague of mine argued that this would be bad design and probably has negative effects on the system per se (that the IDs are not delivered by the database, ie lose of control) or performance (not generating the UUIDs, but on the database side, handling them). Are there any points supporting this claim or is it mumbo-jumbo? I mean, the generator is supplied by Hibernate, it's not like someone must have thought its a good idea, also getting rid of the sequences seems to be a good tradeoff, not that they're bad, more that they feel like overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like sequences (and there are downsides to using them, such as portability across instances), then why not use Oracle's GUID?  It can be used to automatically generate the primary keys also:

```
create table my_tab2
(
val1 raw(16) default sys_guid(),
val2 varchar2(100),
primary key(val1)
)
table MY_TAB2 created.
> insert into my_tab2 (val2) values ('A test val')
1 rows inserted.
> commit
committed.
> select * from my_tab2
VAL1                             VAL2                                                                                               
-------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E8B47FA523673C97E040A8C014175791 A test val
```

You don't even have to care about how the PK is populated (no triggers for a sequence or constantly using seq.nextval in inserts).  Just not very pretty to look at (not a "nice" as numbers I suppose).

Also, if you depend on Hibernate (or any other app/system outside of the database) to generate keys for a table, then that table is beholden, 100% relying on Hibernate or whatever outside system for its ongoing maintenance and integrity.  The data belongs to the company, not the application.  In my opinion, the database layer should be as independent as possible (in this case, simply using Oracle's sys_guid instead of something generated by Hibernate increases the data layers independence).  It may seem trivial in this case, but why not use features that Oracle provides first.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly not using the database to generate a primary key may be the reason to use UUID: You can deploy multiple instances of the application and locally generate the IDs without the need for a global coordinator.
Using the global coordinator can degrade your scalability.

If you do bulk inserts the UUID may be a performance problem since they are evenly distributed over the key space, leading to many possible seeks to make sure the key is unique.

Depending on your database you should consider to tune it with regard to UUID: Postgres has a uuid column, in MySQL you may want to represent it as binary to avoid UTF8 overhead.

An additional benefit for UUID: If you expose the IDs to the frontend/end-user, he can not see how many objects are in your database, nor guess the next id.

Answer (score 0):

A UIID is many times the size of an INTEGER(11), and that alone is going to have a major effect on performance. I don't see any reason *not* to use the facilities already built-in to the data base. It is really you that has to justify that course, not your colleague the opposite.